# Using a two and three column interface in SwiftUI NavigationSplitView app

Tags: swift, swiftui, interface, ios16, swiftui-navigationsplitview

Now I am developing an application and faced with the problem of having to display two and three-column interfaces within the same application.

Let's say that I have two views. The first one should display only the Detail View, and the second one should be with list of ContentView and Detail View.

NavigationSplitView Interfaces Image

[image: 1]

The problem is that sometimes this causes the views to overlap.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("First View") {
                    FirstView()
                }
                NavigationLink("Second View") {
                    SecondView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            Text("Details")
                .navigationTitle("Detail")
        }
        
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("First View Detail")
            .navigationTitle("First Detail")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("First View") {
                    FirstView()
                }
                NavigationLink("Second View") {
                    SecondView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
        } content: {
            Text("Second View Content")
                .navigationTitle("Second Content")
        } detail: {
            Text("Second View Detail")
                .navigationTitle("Second Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

Question. How do I create an application where there is a two and three-column interface?

Comment: NavigationSplitView does not work that way - read documentation carefully.

Comment: Did you find a way?